# why it cannot convert char* to char

Tags: c++

In c++ we can write
1 `char *s="hello"`

but the below lines of program produces an error ( cannot convert char* to char)
2    `char *s; 
  *s="hello";`

I am confused here, what is difference between 1 and 2
why this error is coming?

Comment: The string literal `"hello"` is not a `char *` (and neither is it a `char`).

Comment: "In c++ we can write char *s="hello"" - no, we can't.

Comment: Try `s="hello";`

Comment: Use std::string!

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, I disagree. The focus of this question is how to assign a pointer. While it's worth mentioning that string literals cannot be converted to `char*`, it's not the question.

Comment: Why the close votes? This is neither unclear nor is it a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: @chris I had misread the question. I've retracted my vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A string is an array of characters. The **start** of a string therefore is `const char *`. 
Therefore to reference a string, you can use `const char * s = "hello";`

However if you dereference a `const char*`, you get a `const char`. This isn't a string i.e. `*s` gives you 'h'.

In your code `*s="hello";`, you are saying "assign at the dereferened s the value "hello"". Dereferencing s is a character only, to which you are trying to assign a string.

Answer (score 6):

In C++, a string literal is a *constant* array of characters, not just an array of characters like in C. Anyways, to assign to such a variable (Which is best avoided), you do not have to dereference the pointer.  Dereferencing it accesses the first element, which is just a char. A char cannot hold an array of characters inside it, causing an error. This is more the reason why you should be using [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Some compilers such as GCC provide extensions to make such code possible since it is not standards compliant code, and it would look like:

```
char* s = "hello";
s = "new string";
```

This generates the following warning in [GCC](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0ZVDnKqCLpvnzUcP) (But still gets the expected result):

> warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

[Clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/aqbhXt0q9SS3TNkn) also has the same behavior with the same output (Also generating a warning)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the second asterisk in your second example.

The first code is this

```
char *s="hello";
```

The equivalent code is this

```
char *s; 
s="hello";
```

No `*` before `s` in the second line.

Now as everyone is pointing out neither of these are legal C++. The correct code is

```
const char *s="hello";
```

or

```
const char *s; 
s="hello";
```

Because string literals are constant, and so you need a pointer to `const char`.

Answer (score 0):

> I am confused here, what is difference between 1 and 2 why this error is coming?

As many others  `*` in C++ means different things in different context:

```
char *s; // * here means that s type is a pointer to char, not just char
*s;      // in this context * means dereference s, result of exression is char
int a = 5 * 2; // in this context * means multiply
```

so case 1 and 2 may look similar to you but they mean very different things hence the error.